# Best Practise: Accessing derived classes in a vector which have different member variables and methods

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have some classes `Street`, `Streetlamp`, `House` and `Tree` and so on, which are derived from a base class `AbstractClass`. Both classes have a different set of member variables of a type `Instruction`, which represent instructions on how to "build/plant" a house, a tree or a lamp. For example:

```
class House : public AbstractClass {
public:
  Instruction foundation;
  Instruction walls;
  Instruction roof;
};

class Tree : public AbstractClass {
public:
  Instruction hole;
};
```

A container `vector<AbstractClass*>`, containing different objects is passed to a third class `Builder`, which should use the instructions contained in the elements to "build" them in order. Builder could have a method `void buildElement(AbstractClass*)` and depending on the instructions would have to perform different actions ("digging", "planting", "driving")

Currently i'm using just one class, which holds a lot of (unnecessary) information, including an `enum type` in each object to specify which type it has. 
How can i implement this case of polymorphism efficiently in C++ ?
Is the visitor pattern appliable here ? Or should i use the RTTI mechanisms like `dynamic_cast` and `typeid`. Or is there some better way ?

Comment: Object-oriented programming is apparently not a solution to your problem. You have no abstract *behaviour* but only different data, so there is no useful way to apply object-oriented polymorphism.

Comment: Hmm well, what's the semantic relation of `House` and `Tree` actually? Maybe you should flesh out your use case a bit more illustrative, and also give a sample what you think `AbstractClass` should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an abstract `Build()` method to `AbstractClass`, where each derivative of `AbstractClass` implements `Build()` as needed:

```
class AbstractClass {
public:
    virtual ~AbstractClass() {}
    virtual void Build() = 0;
};

class House : public AbstractClass {
public:
  Instruction foundation;
  Instruction walls;
  Instruction roof;

  virtual void Build() {
    // build foundation, walls, and roof as needed...
  }
};

class Tree : public AbstractClass {
public:
  Instruction hole;
  Instruction plant;

  virtual void Build() {
    // dig hole and plant tree as needed...
  }
};
```

Then `Builder` can loop through the `vector` calling `Build()` on each object:

```
void Builder::buildElements(std::vector<AbstractClass*> &elements) {
  for(std::vector<AbstractClass*>::iterator i = elements.begin(); i != elements.end(); ++i) {
    i->Build();
  }
```

Or:

```
void buildElement(AbstractClass* element) {
    element->Build();
}

void Builder::buildElements(std::vector<AbstractClass*> &elements) {
  std::for_each(elements.begin(), elements.end(), &buildElement);
}
```

Or:

```
void Builder::buildElements(std::vector<AbstractClass*> &elements) {
  std::for_each(elements.begin(), elements.end(),
    [](AbstractClass* element) { element->Build(); }
  );
}
```